# Wordpress ACF - Date format

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I am using the date field to render out the date to look like: 11/15/2014. But I want to also display the date like November 15, 2014 else where on the page. Is it somehow possible to render out the date in two different formats?

```
<?php the_field('date'); ?>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `get_field` and then you can change the date format to whatever you want.

```
$date = get_field('date');
$date2 = date("F j, Y", strtotime($date));
```

Comment: Note: You can also change the "Display Format" or "Return Format" settings when you create the field to alter the format that is returned from "get_field".

Answer (score -1):

For 11/15/2014,

```
the_date('m/d/Y');
```

And for November 15, 2014,

```
the_date('F d, Y');
```