# Fatal error when using advanced custom field date picker

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

```
<?php
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', get_field('event_date'));
 echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
?>
```

I am using Advanced custom field plugin. In there I am facing a problem. The PHP code is not working and giving me a fatal error. I used the same code as the  plugin documentation, but still I am getting an error.

Comment: Did you try this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26941452/wordpress-acf-date-format

Answer (score 0):

First, get the ACF value using get_field() and store it in a variable.

Then use date() and strtotime() to convert that string into desired Date format.

Use the below code.

```
$date = get_field('event_date');
$event_date = date("d-m-Y", strtotime($date));
echo $event_date;
```